# Unable to Draw lines between two listviews or list of buttons in horizontal

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-linearlayout

I am trying to draw lines between two columns consists of 10 buttons in each column like in image showing below. I tried using linear layout.

[image]

```
private void createCHTDesign(int scenarios, int numberOfPlots, ArrayList<Plots> plotsArrayList) {

        headingLayout.clear();
        Log.d(TAG, "scenarios:" + scenarios);
        Log.d(TAG, "headingsize:" + headingLayout.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < scenarios; i++) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (i == 0) {
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

            } else {
                params.setMargins(250, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            mainLayout.addView(linearLayout);
            headingLayout.add(linearLayout);
            Log.d(TAG, "count:" + mainLayout.getChildCount());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < headingLayout.size(); i++) {
            addButtons(headingLayout.get(i), i, numberOfPlots, plotsArrayList);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void addButtons(LinearLayout layout, int index, int numberOfPlots, ArrayList<Plots> plotsArrayList) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
        textView.setText(combinationNames.get(index));
        textView.setTextSize(16);
        layout.addView(textView);


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlots; i++) {

            Button button = new Button(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400, 150);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setId(View.generateViewId());

            button.setText(plotsArrayList.get(i).getMpValue() + "\n" + plotsArrayList.get(i).getYield());
            button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            button.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);
            button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.right2x, 0);
            GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
            gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[i]));
            gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(10);
            gradientDrawable.setStroke(20, Color.parseColor(colors[i]));

            clickonArrow(button.getText().toString(), button);

            button.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
            layout.addView(button);
        }

    }
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            />
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"/>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchCht"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Search CHT"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

              <!--  <com.sma.cht.chtcharacterization.view.MatchTheFollowingAttempted
                    android:id="@+id/match"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                </com.sma.cht.chtcharacterization.view.MatchTheFollowingAttempted>
          -->
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Presently I am getting buttons in both columns but unable to draw lines either you can do this buttons stuff by using listview as well. can you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

divide your cross line in two parts.

try the below code,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerview=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerview.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter());
}
```

}

SampleAdapter.java

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<String> list1;
ArrayList<String> list2;

public SampleAdapter() {
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        list1.add("Left " + i);
        list2.add("Right " + i);
    }
}
@NonNull
@Override
public SampleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new SampleAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SampleAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
    myViewHolder.buttonLeft.setText(list1.get(position));
    myViewHolder.buttonRight.setText(list2.get(position));

    //show partA image
    if (position == 8) {
        myViewHolder.imageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myViewHolder.imageview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    //show partB image
    if (position == 9) {
        myViewHolder.imageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myViewHolder.imageview3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list1.size();
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button buttonLeft, buttonRight;
    ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        buttonLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
        buttonRight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        imageview1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        imageview2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        imageview3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
    }
}}
```

recycle_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="text" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B3D4F3"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/image_a"          android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/image_b  android:visibility="gone" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

image_a.png
[image: image_a]

[image: image2]

image_b.png

[image]

output

Comment: its not like only two listviews we will have 12 listviews and lines should draw according to button color, if left side button has blue color and wherever the rightside button has blue color  is there we need to draw line

Comment: why -1 .as per your question i have posted answer.the image which u posted the resultant output looks same